# Magento Exceptions with existing extensions

Tags: magento

I am having these two different exceptions in Magento ver. 1.6.0.0 and would like to resolve them. This is for an existing site so I am not sure about the history of modules installed. I believe the first one is actually missing the extension files. I searched for this folder "Fbintegrator" and could not find it. Also, not sure if it can be in some other folder. I also looked at the installed extensions in the Magento Connect in the admin and could not find anything related to Fbintegrator which Iam assuming is a facebook_integrator. So I would like to de-register it or if there is a way to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Fbintegrator_Block_Like'     in /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/Mage.php:563
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(469):     Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Core/Layout.php(10):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('fbintegrator/li...', Array)
#2 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(411):     Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Core_Layout->_getBlockInstance('fbintegrator/li...', Array)
#3 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('fbintegrator/li...', 'fbintegrator.li...')
#4 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('fbintegrator/li...', 'fbintegrator.li...')
#5 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),     Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345):     Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#9 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73):     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144):     Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Catalog_Product),     Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#11     /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132):     Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(4299, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController),     Object(Varien_Object))
#12 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420):     Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#13     /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#14 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347):     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home1/gumballm/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home1/gumballm/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

This second extension is actually found in the Magento Connect. I actually also tried uninstalling it and then re-installing it and still getting the same error below. I found the folder: Ezapps/Zoom/ but not the file Ezapps/Zoom/Handler.php even after re-install.

```
2013-11-18T03:02:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Ezapps/Zoom/Handler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home1/gumballm/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first extension, it's hard to say exactly.  I see Aitoc as part of the stack trace which can complicate things.  The extension itself can normally be disabled by finding the extension's file in app/etc/modules and editing the xml to set active to false.  Aitoc complicates things by trying to work resolving extension conflicts itself.  If you can live without the Aitoc extension, the easy solution is to get rid of it.  If it's necessary, try to look through the various Aitoc configuration sections to find their conflict resolutions and remove it for fbintegrator.  It was probably installed when the Aitoc extension was installed, it resolved a conflict by making itself extend fbintegrator, then fbintegrator was removed breaking that dependency.

For the second extension, Ezapps_Zoom_Handler is the class name in the file ezzoom.php.  Part of the installation requires you to add `include('ezzoom.php');` immediately after the opening php tag.  If you don't, when line 533 of app/code/local/Ezapps/Zoom/Helper/Data.php checks if the class exists, the class won't be loaded already and will rely on Magento's auto-loader which will look in the wrong place.